# terminating a ssh connection created by Python pexpect spawn

Tags: python, pexpect

I have created a SSH tunnel using the python pexpect.spawn() command. I would like to close or terminate this ssh connection post my processing. I have tried giving the `<sshtunnel>.close()` / `<sshtunnel>.kill()` / `<sshtunnel>.terminate()` command. Even though, on giving the `<sshtunnel>.isalive()` method I get a value `False` meaning the child process has been closed, I still see the ssh tunnel process running on my linux ubuntu machine.

Any inputs on how to get this ssh tunnel process terminated ?
Here is the brief code snippet.

```
    username="username"
    passwd="password"
    try:
        child=pexpect.spawn("ssh -C2qTnNf -D XXXX xxxx@qualifier1.qualifier2.net")
        i=child.expect('password:')
        print(i)
        if i==0:
            print(passwd)
            time.sleep (0.5)
            child.sendline(passwd)
            child.expect('$')
            time.sleep(2) 
            print(child)
            print(child.isalive())
            print('####')
            child.close(force=True)
           #child.terminate(force=True)
            time.sleep(5)
            print(child.isalive())
            print(child)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Comment: Yes pynexj, it did. Thanks a bunch. Apologies for the late reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh -f` would fork a child `ssh` process running in background (like a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing))) and the parent process would exit immediately.

For `pexpect.spawn('ssh -f ...')`, pexpect can only interact with the parent ssh process so it cannot stop the background *tunnel* ssh process.

To kill the tunnel ssh process you need to find its PID and do something like `os.system('kill ...')` or `os.kill(pid, sig)`.